# Incorrect Total Value in SSRS compared with SSAS when Sum Total used

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have an SSAS cube with that works perfectly. I am trying to use this build a set of SSRS reports however I am running into trouble with the differences between the way things are interpreted in SSAS v SSRS.

I have a very basic calculated field within my SSAS cube that calculates the total number of representatives.

```
Sum([Rep].[RepName].[All], [Measures].[NoReps])
```

In SSAS when I manipulate this by customer, by territory etc it works fine with the total 'accurate'. Being accurate, even if the list is displayed by customer and each customer has 5 reps that

In SSAS

Customers | Rep | Sales | Total Sales | % of Total Sales

Customer 1 | Jane | $500 | $2,000 | 25%

Customer 1 | Mary | $1,250 | $2,000 | 62.5%

Customer 1 | Bill | $250 | $2,000 | 12.5%

Total | Total | $2,000 | $2,000 | 100%

In SSRS

Customers | Rep | Sales | Total Sales | % of Total Sales

Customer 1 | Jane | $500 | $2,000 | 25%

Customer 1 | Mary | $1,250 | $2,000 | 62.5%

Customer 1 | Bill | $250 | $2,000 | 12.5%

Total | Total | $2,000 | **$6,000** | **33%**

What I am doing wrong that I cannot replicate this table in SSRS? Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: When you run the data source in SSRS via dataset properties does it give the expected results?

Answer (score 0):

You must remove SUM() in the totals on the table (or other control). E.g. Sum(Fields!YourFields.Value) by Fields!YourFields.Value